# How do I make a postback trigger concurrently?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, textbox

I have a TextboxSectionName, TextboxSectioncode and Checkbox. When Checkbox gets checked, a text in the TextboxSectionname will be added into TextboxSectioncode, TextboxSectioncode will be read-only, and gets background color; When unchecked, TextboxsectionName gets back.

The problem is process above works fine, but if I try to type more text into textboxSectionName when TextboxSectionCode is still checked, TextboxSectionCode doesn't take a text that has been added to textboxSectionName. To get it working, I have to uncheck the checkbox and check it again.

Is there any way to make the TextboxSectionCode take newly-added text from TextboxSectionName?

Here I have this block of code.

aspx

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSectionCode" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 5px;" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxSectionCode_CheckedChanged"  AutoPostBack="True" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSectionName" runat="server" Width="250px" onkeyup="RefreshUpdatePanel();" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSectionCode" runat="server" Width="250px" ></asp:TextBox>
```

code behind checkbox event handler

```
protected void CheckBoxSectionCode_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBoxSectionCode.Checked == true)
    {
        TextBoxSectionCode.Text = TextBoxSectionName.Text;
        TextBoxSectionCode.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        TextBoxSectionCode.ReadOnly = true;
    }
    else
    {
        TextBoxSectionCode.ReadOnly = false;
        TextBoxSectionCode.Text = "";
        TextBoxSectionCode.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Phillip

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong but it sounds like you may have a misunderstanding of server side code.  Your codebehind will only work when the form is posted back to the server - in your case you have a checkbox which will do it.  If you want to have a real time solution you need to use ajax or just javascript.

I see you have an onkeyup function - that would be one place to put your code.  Depending on your situation and your end goal this may or may not work.

Comment: I did some research and thought onkeyup helps me get this working.. I might need to work with javascript. Thanks for the help!